# Cannot see PXGraph template in visual studio

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to find PXGraph template for customization in visual studio but couldn't find it. Can anyone let me know how to add the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have installed the Acumatica Framework.
Go to Start->Acumatica->Acumatica Framework and run it.

Choose Deploy Acumatica Framework Tools

[image]

And press Finish

[image]

After this installation you should be able to select PXGraph from Add Item dialog

[image]

If I remember correctly the Acumatica's Tools are designed for VS 2015. But you can check the tools from Framework for 2018 R1 may be they have developed them for VS 2017 too.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018 R1 Build 18.111.0019, the Acumatica Framework Tools include templates for both VS 2015 and 2017.